# Java Serialization Problems, while using guava Lists.transform

Tags: java, serialization, guava

I had to serialize a complex object, but one of its component was non-serializable ( a third party graph object), so I created a custom serializable version of this Graph class and used Guava List transform to convert the non-serializable object to the custom objects.  The serialization writeObject still failed. I will be interested to know why? My assumption is that the Lists.transform performs its operation Lazily (Holding an hidden reference to the orginal object.)

Also is there an workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lists.transform() does perform lazily as you suspected.  You could do one of

```
Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(...))
```

or, if you want an immutable version,

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.transform(...))
```

and then serialize the resulting list.

Comment: You don't have to create new list, see @eneveu answer.

Comment: The OP stated that fromList was specifically full of non-serializable elements.

Comment: @Xaerness can you modify your comment ? You can't get a serializable list just by using the enum trick (@eneveu answer). This answer is the most usefull regarding the question.

Answer (score 7):

Lists.transform() returns a transformed view of the original list. From the Lists.transform() [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

> The returned list always implements Serializable, but serialization
>   will succeed only when fromList and function are serializable.

When serializing the transformed view, you are actually serializing the original list, plus the function. In your case, it fails because your original list is not serializable (because it contains non-serializable graph elements). But it could also fail because the function does not implement serializable.

BTW, there is a little trick to create serializable functions without the verbosity. Instead of doing:

```
  private static final class MyFunction extends Function<String, String> implements Serializable {
    private static final MyFunction INSTANCE = new MyFunction();

    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
      return "[" + input + "]";
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
      return INSTANCE;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
  }
```

You can use the enum singleton pattern, which is a lot less verbose, and gets you  serialization for **free** (since enums are serializable). It also makes sure your Function is a singleton:

```
  // enum singleton pattern
  private enum MyFunction implements Function<String, String> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
      return "[" + input + "]";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome... Effective Java. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, Joshua Bloch explains in Effective Java that it's the best way to create a singleton. An enum is serializable, it's not vulnerable to various de-serialization attacks, and the JVM guarantees its unicity. You can find good examples of the pattern in the Guava library: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Functions.java#59

Comment: Bonus points for citing EJ and for applications of good patterns in Guava, even if the answer isn't that useful because `fromList` isn't going to be serializable.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempted to serialize a list returned from Lists#transform, the interface List itself is *not* Serializable.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? It's the implementation that is considered during serialization. And the implementation returned by Lists.transform() does implement Serializable: "The returned list always implements Serializable, but serialization will succeed only when fromList and function are serializable." ( from the [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) )