# Transform collections to client side in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, guava

The following code is a GWT RPC serlvet implementation , 
the transformed collection fails in the client obviously since the since it is not GWT compatible.

Any soutions inside [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) that I am missing ?

```
@Singleton
public class DataServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        DataService {

    @Inject
    ApplicationDao dao;

    @Inject
    DtoUtil dtoUtil;

    public Collection<GoalDto> getAllConfiguredGoals() {
        return Collections2.transform(dao.getAllGoals(), new Function<Goal, GoalDto>() {
            public GoalDto apply(@Nullable Goal goal) {
                return dtoUtil.toGoalDto(goal);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am looking for a native guava solution , not some hand written translation code.

Comment: Slightly related question on serializing transformed collections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418032/java-serialization-problems-while-using-guava-lists-transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with guava in this case is that it uses Lazy-evaluation (which is often good, but not here) and the collection is backed-up by the original collection. The only way out would be to force a new collection which is not backed-up by original objects and where all evaluations have been performed. Something like this should do the trick (assuming that GoalDto is GWT-serializable):

```
return new ArrayList<GoalDto>(Collections2.transform(dao.getAllGoals(), new Function<Goal, GoalDto>() {
        public GoalDto apply(@Nullable Goal goal) {
            return dtoUtil.toGoalDto(goal);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: I think the original would work fine if the `Function` object was GWT-serializable.

Comment: Perhaps so, but it may be missing the point. Why transform a `Goal` to a `GoalDTO` on the server if you're going to actually be having the client do that work in the end? We often use a TO in this situation because the object as used by the server contains more information than the client needs. Either this is a security concern or a performance concern. Either way, you want to do the eval on the server side.

Comment: That said, personally, I'd prefer to use `ImmutableList.copyOf(...)` rather than `new ArrayList(...)`

Comment: @LouisWasserman this would also require that the Goal being GWT-Serializable which is not that often the case (typically entities from JPA).

Comment: @Ray good point on the immutable list. Is the returned List compatible with GWT?

Comment: Yes. See the JavaDoc (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) which shows this class has the annotation: `@GwtCompatible(serializable=true, emulated=true)`